# Декоратор с приоритетом

Tags: ооп, проектирование, шаблоны-проектирования

Предположим, есть класс Entity с методом doSth() и несколько декораторов к нему (EntityDecorator1, EntityDecorator2 и т. д.). Можно ли сделать так, чтобы у декораторов был приоритет вне зависимости от порядка применения декораторов к классу?
Пример:

```
Entity e = new Entity();
e = new EntityDecorator1(e);
e = new EntityDecorator2(e);
e = new EntityDecorator3(e);
e.doSth();
```

Приоритет декораторов такой: EntityDecorator2, EntityDecorator1, EntityDecorator3 (по возрастанию). Теперь при вызове e.doSth() должен вызываться сначала метод из EntityDecorator3, потом из EntityDecorator1, потом из EntityDecorator2.

Comment: Что мешает просто декорировать объект нужной последовательностью декораторов?

Comment: вам в таком случае вообще не нужен декоратор, смотрите в сторону chain of responsibility, или observer. в последнем легко отсортировать слушателей по приоритетам перед рассылкой уведомлений

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовал гибрид решений [[@jmu](/users/1810/jmu)](/users/1810/jmu) и [[@Dith](/users/8139/dith)](/users/8139/dith). `Entity` завернул в контейнер, в котором хранил список декораторов отсортированных по приоритету. Да, получился не совсем декоратор, но это работает и выглядит достаточно красиво.

Answer (score 1):

Набросал быстренько от руки, просьба сильно не ругать, такие вещи необходимо тщательно продумывать. Да и конечный результат может варьироваться от задачи.
Идея состоит в том, чтобы сделать декоратор, который бы аггрегировал другие декораторы с нужным приоритетом.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

//декорируемый класс
class Entity
{
public:
    virtual void d()
    {
        cout <<"Entity"<<endl;
    }
};

//классический декоратор
class Decorator : public Entity
{
public:
    Decorator()
        :m_entity(NULL)
    {
    }

    explicit Decorator(Entity* ent)
        :m_entity(ent)
    {
    }

    virtual void d()
    {
        if(m_entity)
            m_entity->d();
    }

private:
    Entity* m_entity;
};

//классический конкретный декоратор 1
class Decor1 : public Decorator
{
public:
    Decor1()
    {
    }

    explicit Decor1(Entity* ent)
        :Decorator(ent)
    {
    }

    virtual void d()
    {
        Decorator::d();
        cout <<"Decor1"<<endl;
    }
};

//классический конкретный декоратор 2
class Decor2 : public Decorator
{
public:
    Decor2()
    {
    }

    explicit Decor2(Entity* ent)
        :Decorator(ent)
    {
    }

    virtual void d()
    {
        Decorator::d();
        cout <<"Decor2"<<endl;
    }
};

//классический конкретный декоратор 3
class Decor3 : public Decorator
{
public:
    Decor3()
    {
    }

    explicit Decor3(Entity* ent)
        :Decorator(ent)
    {
    }

    virtual void d()
    {
        Decorator::d();
        cout <<"Decor3"<<endl;
    }
};

//вот он декоратор - комбинатор
class CombineDecorator : public Decorator
{
public:
    explicit CombineDecorator(Entity* ent)
    {
        m_entities.insert(std::make_pair(100500, ent));
    }

    void add(int order, Entity* ent)
    {
        m_entities.insert(make_pair(order, ent));
    }

    void remove(int order, Entity* ent)
    {
        m_entities.erase(order);
    }

    void d()
    {
        for (EntityMap::iterator i = m_entities.begin(); i!= m_entities.end(); ++i)
        {
            i->second->d();
        }
    }

private:    
    typedef std::map<int, Entity*>  EntityMap;
    EntityMap               m_entities;
};

int main()
{
    //обычное использование
    Entity* ent = new Entity();
    ent = new Decor1(ent);
    ent = new Decor2(ent);
    ent->d();

    cout <<"========"<<endl;

    //кобинатор отдельно

    Entity* ent2 = new Entity();
    CombineDecorator* cd = new CombineDecorator(ent2);
    cd->add(3, new Decor1());
    cd->add(4, new Decor2());
    cd->add(2, new Decor3());
    ent2 = cd;

    ent2->d();

    cout <<"========"<<endl;

    //совместное использование
    cd->add(6, ent);
    ent2->d();
}
```

Comment: Этот подход становится бессмысленным, когда вам дают некоторый `Entity*`, который уже продекорирован через `CombineDecorator*`, поскольку для него приоритеты новых декораторов не смержатся с приоритетами старых декораторов.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать согласен, но это не баг, а фича! Подобное поведение не требовалось изначальной задачей, не так ли?. Сделать общий приоритет для одной иерархии декорирования, думается, не есть не реализуемая задача.